# Send date from client to server

Tags: javascript, .net, datetime, date

I want to send data from client and create it on server.  So:
1) How can I get the total milliseconds count by JavaScript `Date` object?
2) How can I create .NET `DateTime` object by total milliseconds count?

Comment: Total milliseconds since when? If you look at the [doco for the JavaScript Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) you'll see there is a method to get the total milliseconds between a specified date and 1 Jan 1970 - is that what you mean?

Comment: I just want to send data from client and create it on server.

Comment: Can you use jQuery? It will make it almost trivial to use.

Comment: Yes, I can. How JQuery can help me?

Comment: See my answer and its edit. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use AJAX for this. Once you send the `d.getTime()` as explained by the other answer, parse it like this in your C# code behind:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["milliseconds"]))
{
    long clientSideMS = Int64.Parse(Request.Form["milliseconds"]);
    DateTime past = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
    DateTime clientSideDate = past.AddMilliseconds(clientSideMS);
}
```

After this, `clientSideDate` will be the date on the client side.

Edit: using jQuery, posting the date is as simple as:

```
var now = new Date();
var ms = now.getTime();
$.post("Page.aspx", { milliseconds: ms.toString() } );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = new Date();
alert(d.getMilliseconds()); // for the milliseconds between the current seconds
alert(d.getTime()); // for the milliseconds since Midnight, Jan 1, 1970
```

Comment: Also: `d.getTime();` or even just `+d` to coerce to number — less to type. :-)

Comment: @user828584, what about .NET `DateTime` ?